# Background file is not loading for image sprite

Tags: css, image, sprite

I created a photo gallery for my websites, and on my latest site I thought I'd contain the CSS and all page files in a sub-folder called 'gallery', thinking this would be easier because I could use it like a plug-in on other sites.

Here's the gallery page: http://unserclosecustoms.com/gallery/galleries.php

The new problem has to do with the image sprite I use for the navigation graphics on my photo.php page. This is the page where you scroll through the large-size images one at a time.

Here's a sample link to the photo page: http://unserclosecustoms.com/gallery/photo.php?curPage=12&g=33&t=19

The sprite file, gallerylinks.png is located in a folder called 'graphics' the site's root directory. I decided to change the location for the sprite file and place it inside the 'gallery' folder in a folder called 'graphics'. I changed the `background` paths in my CSS file for the gallery, and when I went to try it...no image sprite. I checked the spelling in the paths letter by letter a dozen times and still, no luck.

When I change the paths in the CSS file back to the 'graphics' folder in the root directory it works fine. I have no idea why changing the location of the sprite file (and the appropriate `background` paths in CSS) would make a difference. I checked this in Firefox 17 (my primary browser) and Chrome 23, same result, so I don't think it's a browser issue.

I can live with the sprite file in it's current location, but I'd rather have it in the 'graphics' folder inside the 'gallery' folder. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://unserclosecustoms.com/graphics/gallerylinks.png works for me, but I see no such file at http://unserclosecustoms.com/graphics/gallery/gallerylinks.png

Comment: @j No, the site works fine. What I'm saying is that when the file gets moved, it stops functioning. As mentioned above, the place I experimented moving it to was /gallery/graphics/gallerylinks.png

Comment: Well we can't troubleshoot it unless you put it back to the not working state.

Comment: @j It's now in the non-working state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the above re using virtual paths rather than relative paths. You'll eliminate a lot of headaches this way.

Without seeing the page in it's non-working form it's hard to troubleshoot this. My best guess, however, is that it was probably related to moving the file, and moving the images, and that your relative path was horked.

Am I reading the above correctly, and you are trying to have your page at /gallery/photo.php and the image at /gallery/graphics/gallerylinks.png?  If that was the case, relative to the page, the correct rel path would be ../graphics/gallerylinks.png.

Again, though, save all these needless headaches and follow the advice of using virtual paths as a rule - then when you decide to move a page life is still good since you're always starting at the root.

Comment: adding the `../` was what I was missing. THANK YOU for that!

Answer (score 0):

See if you can avoid paths relative to where your CSS file is:

```
#back a:hover {
   background: url(../../graphics/gallerylinks.png) -160px -30px;
}
```

and instead use root paths with a leading `/` (after you move the file):

```
#back a:hover {
   background: url(/gallery/graphics/gallerylinks.png) -160px -30px;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did as you sugegsted and changed the paths to `/graphics/gallerylinks.png`, the png file is located in the 'graphics folder inside the 'gallery folder. But...it doesn't show up now.

Comment: I see `background: url/graphics/gallerylinks.png);` with a missing `(` but using `background: url(/gallery/graphics/gallerylinks.png);` should work since the image appears to be there

Comment: Crikey, thanks for that! I added the `(` back, but still it does not work.